# FirebaseCrashlytics auto upload-symbols problem

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to implement new FirebaseCrashlytics in my iOS app and having some issues and some things are not clear at all.

As per [Upgrade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=ios) doc in step 3, I have to add following run script:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
```

so, in my case it is:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols"
```

But compile was failing because:

```
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Validation succeeded. Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode
[31merror: No Google App ID or Google Services file provided[0m
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

If I delete `upload-symbols` line it is working fine, I'm getting crashes in Dashboard, but as far as I understand this `upload-symbols` has to upload `dSYM` files of app users, so I have no worry about this. Means I still need it...

So I tried to replace them:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

And it started to compile.

I did a force crash and got it in Dashboard, but also I got:
[image]

Does it mean that it is not working and it is must be after `run`, so I continued and finished with:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}"
```

Now I was able to compile, but still getting optional `dSYM` in Dashboard.

Now I'm completely lost, if anyone can clarify it would be great.

PS: I'm able to use `upload-symbols` from terminal, but it is kind of manual job.

Few more questions as a discussion:

1. Why in [Upgrade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=ios) docs it is `run` and `upload` script, but in [Get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) only `run`?
2. In [Upgrade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=ios) docs it is exact path for `${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run` but not exact for `/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols` they are same folder, why not use same?
3. in [Get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) docs there are input files and one of them is `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` why they are using `(`, not `{`?
4. This path `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` is path to `Info.plist` file, not to `GoogleService-Info.plist` why they gave it then?)

Comment: I am also facing problems with it... my dsym files are always missing even though I do the steps properly... did you figure this out?

Comment: As of now, no :(

Comment: For me when I am in debug and try to simulate a crash, I could see the entry, but with ipa no luck

Comment: I saw somewhere that if you enable bit code (in my project it is enabled), these dSYM won't give you any benefit and you still might need upload manually - maybe it is your case.

Comment: Yeah bit code is enabled... but I didn’t see this info in Google’s doc

Comment: Finally I fixed my problem....if bitcode is enabled you have to download dysm from Appstore connect and manually upload it... once I did that...atleast some logs started working